# Jest crashes on require('react')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to set up Jest in a new React project.

package.json:

```
"dependencies" : {
  "react": "^0.13.1",
  "jest-cli": "^0.4.5",
  "babel-jest": "^5.2.0"
}, 
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest"
},
"jest": {
  "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/static/preprocessor.js",
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["react"],
  "testFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "jsx"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "jsx"
  ],
  "testPathDirs": [
    "<rootDir>/static/app"
  ],
  "testDirectoryName": "test",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/bower_components/"
  ]
}
```

Test-test.js:

```
jest.dontMock('../scripts/components/shared/Test');

describe('Test', () => {
  var Test = require('../scripts/components/shared/Test');
  it('registers test', () => {
    expect("yes").toEqual("yes");
  });
});
```

Test.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
```

When I run `npm test` on the above, I get the following:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:project user$ npm test

> Project@0.0.1 test /Users/user/Projects/project
> jest

Using Jest CLI v0.4.5
Waiting on 1 test...My-MacBook-Pro:project user$
```

If I change Test.jsx to `require('lodash')`, I get the following:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:project user$ npm test

> Project@0.0.1 test /Users/user/Projects/project
> jest

Using Jest CLI v0.4.5
 PASS  static/app/test/Test-test.js (0.517s) 
1 test passed (1 total)
Run time: 0.731s
My-MacBook-Pro:project user$
```

It seems that adding 'react' module causes Jest to crash (without any logging in terminal). I suspect there's something wrong with my configuration, but I can't seem to find what.

Also, is there a way to get more verbose logging? Right now it crashes with no output... I bet I could investigate better if I had some kind of output.

Comment: Did you install react? I Dont see it in your package.

Comment: I have it installed... I'll update my post to include relevant dependencies

Comment: Does it make any difference if you move the line where you require Test inside of the it() function?

Comment: No, moving the `var Test = require(...)` inside the it() function doesn't help. I get the same thing. I wonder if there's a way to get more verbose logging, because right now it just crashes with no output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar issue. I think the problem lies in the fact that Jest doesn't support node versions above 0.10.x ([source](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/243)). I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to run your tests in a supported version.

*edited for tense

Comment: Hi @humble.rumble, I should have used the correct tense. I _was_ having a similar issue and my answer to the user's question solved it. With that said, I _still_ recommend using nvm to run his tests since Jest doesn't support anything above node 0.10.x

Comment: Thanks @HammelAm, that seems to help! I'm now seeing an error -- `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register`. Thoughts there?

Comment: To follow up, use iojs instead of node. `nvm install iojs` and rerun your tests.